# Ampscript and SmartCapture

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a landing page in ET and I am trying to use the smart capture because I want to send a welcome email as soon as the user is added to the data extension.

However, the trigger requires the data extension to have a subscriberkey and email address field and in my case the data for those is the same so I only want to display one input field in the form so someone doesn't have to enter their email twice.

I keep getting error code 2.

This is my code:

```
%%[[name="FormPost";type="POST"] 
 VAR @de, @de_col, @de_statusCode, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode
Set @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("SubscriberKey")
IF IsNull(@SubscriberKey) OR Empty(@SubscriberKey) then
Set @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("EmailAddress")
ENDIF

IF RequestParameter("OptIn") == "true" THEN
SET @OptIn = "true"
ELSE
SET @OptIn = "false"
ENDIF  
SET @de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@de, "CustomerKey", "OptIn_Welcome")


IF NOT IsNull(@SubscriberKey) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", @SubscriberKey)
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("EmailAddress")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "EmailAddress")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("EmailAddress"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("OptIn")) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "OptIn")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", RequestParameter("OptIn"))
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF

IF NOT IsNull(Now()) THEN
SET @de_col = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Name", "DateUpdated")
SetObjectProperty(@de_col, "Value", Now())
AddObjectArrayItem(@de, "Properties", @de_col)
ENDIF
SET @de_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@de, @de_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @de_statusCode != "OK" THEN
RaiseError(@de_statusMsg, 0, @de_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: Hey gaudy - did i manage to answer your question in full? :) or is there more i can do to help?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to display one input field, you should only have one variable, but use that variable in multiple places. E.g.

```
VAR @subscriberkey
SET @subscriberkey = RequestParameter("YourField")
```

`CreateObject("TriggeredSend")`

set email = `@SubscriberKey`

set subscriberkey = `@SubscriberKey`

and then run through the rest of the code.

If you need to upsert data into a data extension for tracking purposes, then simply use;

```
UpsertDate("YourDE",1,"SubscriberKey",@SubscriberKey,"Email",@SubscriberKey)
```

Hope this helps